Does setting a writable signal to the same value as before mark a component as dirty?
I know that computed signals and effects are lazily evaluated and memoized. They don't do more work than needed. But if I do this in an Angular component:
derpSignal = signal("derp")

functionThatGetsCalledRandomly() {
  derpSignal.set("derp")
}

Does the component get marked dirty every time derpSignal gets set, independent of the previous value? Or does that happen only if the value changes?
Meaning, should I in this case wrap it in
if(derpSignal() !== "derp") {
  derpSignal.set("derp")
}

or is that check already done by the signal itself?

Best you try it out, from what I can see, only when the value changes the signal fires, but please note this important point
Primitive types -> Number, String, Boolean, Undefined, Null and Symbol
Signal fires when the actual value changes ( 1 != 2 -> change fires )
Non-Primitive Types -> Object, Array, etc.
Are stored as references in memory.
Signal fires when the memory reference changes ( memref != memref2 change fires )
Also when you change a nested property of a non primitive type, the reference does not change!
Please check the below example, where setting the value does not trigger a change on either the effect or the computed signal!
import { Component, computed, effect, signal } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.dev/overview">
      Learn more about Angular
    </a>
    {{computedSignal()}}
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  derpSignal = signal('derp');
  computedSignal = computed(() => {
    const signalData = this.derpSignal();
    console.log(signalData, 'changed computed');
  });

  constructor() {
    effect(() => {
      const signalData = this.derpSignal();
      console.log(signalData, 'changed effect');
    });
  }

  functionThatGetsCalledRandomly() {
    this.derpSignal.set('derp');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.functionThatGetsCalledRandomly();
    }, 1000);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo
